# How to install python as a user

Tags: python, vagrant, pip

I need to install python so I can install pip/fab which do not need root access to run and install things. I'm setting up a vagrant VM environment which needs to run fab as non root to function and I really don't want to sudo everything or start changing permissions.

I know with OSX I can install python with brew which will install python to /usr/local/bin or something and then I can just edit my bash_profile path to look in that directoy first.

Comment: Do you need to install python without root permission?

Comment: `pip` doesn't need root. Just do `pip --user install ..`

Comment: I had to run pip with sudo in order to install fabric, and then my fab commands wouldnt work because it couldn't access certain folders without root perms

Comment: You don't *have* to, and you shouldn't have. It's not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Use virtual environments. This allows you to make unlimited amounts of virtual python environments, so you can easily use different sets of packages for different projects. Install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

Then:

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Then, append the following to your bashrc file:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
mkdir -p ~/Envs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Then, suppose we want to make a virtual environment called "test-env" we can execute:

```
mkvirtualenv test-env
```

To use it:

```
workon test-env
```

From within this environment you can then pip install anything (without sudo!).

To exit your virtual environment:

```
deactivate
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. You can install python into your home directory. So you don't need to have root permissions but little bit ground work needed to do so. Follow the answer.

Open your terminal , assume you are installing python to your home directory.

```
mkdir python
cd python
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz
tar -xvf Python-2.7.6.tgz
cd Python-2.7.6
```

Then now, while doing `configure`, you must mention that where you are trying to install it.

so like

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/python
make
make install
```

So right now your python has installed in your home at python named directory. so your system must now that the python which it has to access is over there. So little but bashrc need to be done.

In terminal type:
    nano ~/.bashrc

Then add as

```
export PATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.6/:$PATH
```

and save -exit with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

then do

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Recommended : restart your PC to update the new environment setting we've made.

That's it. Now on wards your system call `python` from your home directory.

[Source](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/python-install)

Answer (score 0):

You can safely install Python as a Local / Non-root user by executing the below code with the required Python Version defined in the variable "PYTHON_VER"

```
# Install Python3 and Libraries as a local user. 
python_config() {
    export PYTHON_VER="3.10.5" 
    export PYTHON_VER_SHORT="$(echo ${PYTHON_VER} | cut -d '.' -f1,2)" 
    cd ~ 
    rm -rf ~/python && mkdir -p ~/python 
    echo "" >> ~/.bashrc 
    echo "export PATH=~/python/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc 
    source ~/.bashrc 
    wget --quiet --no-check-certificate "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VER}/Python-${PYTHON_VER}.tgz" 
    tar -zxvf ~/Python-${PYTHON_VER}.tgz 1>/dev/null 
    cd ~/Python-${PYTHON_VER}/ 
    echo "Python ${PYTHON_VER} - Installing in current logged-in user - $(whoami)" 
    echo "Python ${PYTHON_VER} - Installation in-progress. Please wait..." 
    ./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=$HOME/python > /dev/null 2>&1; 
    echo "Python ${PYTHON_VER} - ETA: upto 5mins. Please wait..." 
    make altinstall > /dev/null 2>&1; 
    ln -s ~/python/bin/python${PYTHON_VER_SHORT} ~/python/bin/python3 
    ln -s ~/python/bin/pip${PYTHON_VER_SHORT} ~/python/bin/pip3 
    wget --quiet --no-check-certificate https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -O - | python3 - --prefix=$HOME/python 
    source ~/.bashrc 
    ~/python/bin/pip3 install --upgrade pip 
    ~/python/bin/pip3 install --upgrade pygithub 
    ~/python/bin/pip3 install --upgrade --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt --use-pep517 
    cd ~ && rm -rf ~/Python-${PYTHON_VER}* 
    ~/python/bin/python3 --version 
    ~/python/bin/pip3 --version 
    echo "Python ${PYTHON_VER} - Setup Completed!" 
}

# Function Call
python_config
```